# $routeChangeError not called on $q.reject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, angular-routing

I have an Angular JS app with a Sails JS backend, and inside the routes (in app.js) I've got:

```
.state('app.detail', {
  url: "/detail",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/detail.html",
      controller: 'UserUpdateCtrl',
      resolve: {
        auth: ["$q", "userData", function($q, userData) {
          var userInfo = userData.getUserInfo();
          if (userInfo) {
            return $q.when(userInfo);
          } else {
            return $q.reject({ authenticated: false });
          }
        }]
      },
    }
  }
})
```

(this is following [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-authentication-angular-applications/))

Now on the same file, I have the $routeChangeError:

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, current, previous, eventObj) {
    if (eventObj.authenticated === false) {
      $location.path("/login");
    }
  });
```

When debugging on chrome, I see that the function is defined, but not called. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe you don't have < ui-view >?

Comment: Pretty sure you want `$stateChangeError`...

Comment: Ok it's calling `$stateChangeError` but the `eventObj.authenticated` var is undefined (eventObj: `Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}`)

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're using Angular UI's router rather than the official router?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay so under the assumption you are using the Angular UI router, I believe you are just translating the error handler incorrectly from the official one.

From the [docs for `$state`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.%24state):

> Fired when an error occurs during transition. It's important to note that if you have any errors in your resolve functions (javascript errors, non-existent services, etc) they will not throw traditionally. You must listen for this $stateChangeError event to catch ALL errors.

And the parameters for this handler are different, try something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  if (error && !error.authenticated) {
    $location.path("/login");
  }
});
```

Here's a description of the parameters with the important one bolded:

- event – {Object} – Event object.
- toState – {State} – The state being transitioned to.
- toParams – {Object} – The params supplied to the toState.
- fromState – {State} – The current state, pre-transition.
- fromParams – {Object} – The params supplied to the fromState.
- **error – {Error} – The resolve error object.**

Comment: Everything works but the `$location.path` which for some reason doesn't redirect (the path part is correct if that helps)

Comment: Come on man there's a pattern here with your issues, you are using $state instead of $location.  Read the docs, it's probably supposed to be `$state.go()` or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sometimes angularjs makes me forget how basic logic works.